# Clicking Floating ActionButton on right corner makes RecyclerView item get clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I want to add Floating Action Button on recyclerview but problem is when i click on Floating Action Button Recyclerview item get clicked how to remove this problem

see below code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.ShowSubjectsFrag"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/MainList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/MainList"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: add clickable attribute to floating button xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Write the `View#onClickListener` for the `FloatingActionButton` in your `Activity/Fragment` because currently your `FloatingActionButton` is not registered for any `event`.
Had the same problem
Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Please try using below code in your xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/MainList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/MainList"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Put both view in different layouts so they can relate to different z levels.

For more information check design practices [here](https://www.google.co.in/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button).

Thanks..!!

Comment: This won't work. You cannot have two root elements in your layout file.

Comment: @ Michael Peterson: Sorry for misunderstanding here. the code given is a part of layout file only. you can put it a single root view group.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `RecyclerView` inside a `RelativeLayout` and you have set its `width` and `height` both to `match_parent`! Basically your `RecyclerView` is hiding your `FloatingActionButton`.

If I were you, I would do the following:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.ShowSubjectsFrag"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/MainList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp" <!-- Use a fixed height over here -->
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/MainList" 
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also suspect that the `layout_anchor` is not required. Try removing it as well. Regardless, the main problem seems to me to be that your `RecyclerView` is hiding your `FloatingActionButton`. You can check the same in the *Design area* (If you are using Android Studio).

Let me know if it helps, otherwise I'll deep dive further!

Comment: Using a fixed height isn't a good solution to this problem in general. It will only lead to other UI issues such as the list being too short on larger devices.